# How to use notebooks on remote machines?

Tags: front-end, remote-access

I need to use a notebook (the command line mathematica can't debug image stuff) and it has to be in EC2 (because of hardware needs). I managed to do this on a remote machine in aws using X11 windows forwarding, but, there is a huge slowdown in using the notebook, just look at the refresh rate:

[image]

Here's the ssh command I used:

```
ssh -XC -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour -i aws.pem -nNT -L 80:localhost:80 ubuntu@ec2-XX-XXX-XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

So here's my question in two parts:

1. Is there a more responsive way to run mma front-end on a remote machine?
2. How to detach a long-running notebook computation in the style of tmux/screen style?

Comment: The great Sascha Kratky once gave a nice [talk](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) on this, and some years ago I even got it to work, but it was too slow for me and I did not really need it.

Comment: Have you seen [Tunnel](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/237/Tunnel)?

Comment: Tunnel no longer works in v11.1

Comment: You could try to get xvnc or xrdp working. Or just use commercial solutions like "Exceed on Demand" from opentext.com or TeamViewer from teamviewer.com

Comment: Are you running X Windows on your Windows? That will speed X11 forwarding. I use Cygwin/X and is fastest, I have seen for X11 refreshing, Linux (headless) Server to Windows 10 Client. https://x.cygwin.com/